# Kalman filter for RSSI in iOS

Tags: ios, filtering, kalman-filter, rssi

I've made an iOS App to range the beacons. I've noticed that the RSSI value from beacons is fluctuating randomly with time. In order to get smooth RSSI value, I am trying to use Kalman filter.

In Kalman filter equations [as described here](http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~varsha/allpapers/mypapers/wcnc.pdf), the measurement noise (R) can be calculated by measuring variance from series of RSSI values and the process noise (Q) can be assumed as negligible. However, I couldn't figure out exact idea about the estimate of error variance (P) in the equation.

Since my actual measurement data is the series of RSSI values, how am I supposed to implement Kalman filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the estimate of error variance(P) depends on it's own past value and the process noise(Q). Since the process noise(Q) is negligible or very small value (0.00001) and P doesn't depend on actual measurement, eventually it becomes a fixed value. Moreover if your system is mobile, you can take series of RSSI values and your movement as input variables.